Using override constants in WebGPU
In the WebGPU spec, both GPUVertexState and GPUFragmentState implement GPUProgrammableStage.  The latter contains the constants field where one specifies the values of pipeline-overrideable constants.
That means that there are two different places within the GPURenderPipelineDescriptor
where you can specify the pipeline-overrideable constants when creating a pipeline.
It is unclear how these two different locations interact.  The specification makes it clear that one can override the value of a variable that is not statically used by that stage's entrypoint.
What does it mean if a constant is overridden with different values in each of the stages? Will anything called from the vertex stage see one value and anything called from the fragment stage see the other?  (This seems wrong!). Does one value override the other?
Why was the constants field placed in GPUProgrammableStage rather than in GPURenderPipelineDescriptor and GPUComputePipelineDescriptor?
